# Can i download a pdf file saved in media in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I need to set create a page on which i have button and on clicking, it should redirect to a registration page and then download a pdf file. so i created a document type in Umbraco which have a file Upload field and i uploaded one file through it. On its template i have added a macro which have a partial view for the registration page. After completing registration, this pdf file should download automatically.

My problem is, the file i uploaded is not showing in the Media library. but the Url is as follows: /media/1051/filname.pdf .

[image]

am getting this url in controller. but couldn't get the file usinng its id.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage DownloadFile([FromBody] DownloadEBookViewModel model)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(model.Url.Split('/')[2]);
            var media = Umbraco.Media(id).Url;


            if (!File.Exists(media))
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            HttpResponseMessage Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);


            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(media);

            if (fileData == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            Response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);
            Response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            return Response;
        }
```

Someone please help. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with the Umbraco helper in code behind, I would advise to use the typed variants for getting items

`var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(id).Url;`

This will give you a strongly typed model with intellisense

To get the physical file from the media object you'll probably want to call

`byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(media.getPropertyValue("umbracoFile"));`

instead of:

`byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(media);`

(code is untested)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it really helped me